# Fancybox AJAX encoding issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, character-encoding, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have a website entirely in English. Using Spring and Bakcbone.js. In one of the views I dynamically create a list each li of which is a fancybox link. On click it loads content of the popup using AJAX. Here is what I have for fancybox init:

```
$(".fancyboxA").fancybox({
            type : 'ajax',
            fitToView : false,
            autoSize : true,
            autoCenter : false,
            helpers : {
                overlay : {
                    locked : false
                }
            }
        });
```

I've used fancybox to load images in another place on my site and things work. 
This time I am loading a simple page via AJAX which all it does is displaying a text that is coming from properties file. The text is in Cyrillic.  I get bunch of ?????????

Couple of things:

1. I have set encoding on the page, in the servlet xml, and properties
   file save using UTF-8
2. I do display portion of the same text on the
   page (the clickable text of LI that calls the fancybox) and it
   displays correctly. It is only when it comes in the fancybox that
   gives me the problem.

I check Fancybox code and it does not change encoding of jQuery ajax call. I check documentation, and jQuery by default is using UTF-8

Any ideas of what I might be missing?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks JFK for editing the title. I couldn't find how to do it :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my problem.

After a deeper analysis of responses I was getting from the server, I found out that I was still getting a wrong character encoding. Apparently, all the configs that I did in Spring XML files were not enough for AJAX calls. It was good enough for regular pages, but not for the content loaded dynamically using AJAX.

So I was able to solve this problem by setting the encoding right at the method that returns the content like so:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/mySuperPage")
public ModelAndView getMySupercontent(@RequestParam int id, HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap map, HttpServletResponse response) {
    map.put("mySuperStuff", uiContentRetriever.getSuperStuff(id));
    //This is what does the trick
    response.setContentType("text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
    return new ModelAndView("/mySuperPage", map);
}
```

Comment: I've been trying to figure out this problem for months with a java web app, thinking it was due to old drivers. This is the answer that fixed it!

Comment: @Pinny Unfortunately, it did not worked for me. Could you please have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31351626/jquery-fancybox-with-ajax/31352383)  question? Thanks in advance.