# jQuery FancyBox with Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, fancybox, asp.net-ajax

I have look at many web sites and many pages on Stackoverflow, but none of them has solved my problem yet. Simply, I have a `hyperlink` and I want to retrieve an image from database via `Ajax` call and then display it on `FancyBox` popup. I also tried many different combinations of `Javascript` and `Controller` action methods, but have not managed so display the downloaded file properly. Could you please have a look at my code and give a working example containing all the necessary methods in `View` and in `Controller`? On the other hand, it would be better to open a dialog for the other file types (i.e. excel, pdf) while opening `FancyBox` for image files.

**View:**

```
<a onclick="downloadFile(@Model.ID);">@Model.FileName</a>


function downloadFile(id) {     
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Issue/RenderImage?ID=" + id,
        async: true,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (response) {
            $('#fancybox-inner').html('<img height="200" width="250" src="data:image/png;base64,' + response + '" />');
        }       
    });
}
```

**Controller:** There is no problem regarding to the method in the Controller and it returns the image properly.

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual JsonResult RenderImage(int id)
{
    string str = System.Convert.ToBase64String(repository.FileAttachments.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == id).FileData, 0, repository.FileAttachments.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == id).FileData.Length);
    return Json(new { Image = str, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Better try

```
success: function (response) {
    $.fancybox({
        content: '<img height="200" width="250" src="data:image/png;base64,' + response + '" />',
        type: "html"
    });
}
```

I wonder why you trying to load the content inside a fancybox container when you don't show any code where you already opened it. Anyways, it's always better to launch a new fancybox with the new content (from ajax response)

Of course, this will work if the ajax call is returning the correct response for your `<img>` tag, but that I cannot tell.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Looks like image is stored as JSON. If so, I think you should convert it back to Base64 before sending it to the browser. See http://mobile.cs.fsu.edu/converting-images-to-json-objects/

```
function downloadFile(id) {
    $('#fancybox-inner').html('<img height="200" width="250" src="/Issue/RenderImage?ID='+id+'" />');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, image is stored as byte[]. I also have a look at the page you mentioned but I am really very confused for the method in the Controller and the Javascript method. On the other hand, your sample does not use Ajax, is it possible to retrieve the image without postback? If we do not use Ajax, I think it seems to be impossible. So, could you check this and clarify me about the what that I should follow? :(

Comment: I'm not sure what server-side language you're using but if you have it return the proper headers and the image in a regular jpeg or png format my method will work. You should get more consistent cross browser results if you don't rely on the browser to convert the image